# ADF - How to copy an Excel Sheet with Multiple Sheets into separate .csv files

Tags: excel, copy, azure-data-factory

I currently have an Excel file that has multiple worksheets (over 11). This Excel file currently lives in a remote file server. I am trying to use Azure Data FactoryV2 to copy the Excel file and split each worksheet as its own .csv file within an ADLS Gen2 folder. The reason for this is because not every tab has the same schema and I want to only select the valid ones later.

I currently have an ADF dataset pointing to the Excel dataset correctly and have created a parameter for the sheet name using @dataset.SheetName. I am not sure where to go next. After creating a new pipeline I have tried nesting a Copy Activity inside a ForEach activity, however, it asks for the SheetName value.

How do I construct this pipeline to grab the names of the worksheets existing in the Excel file and then iterate a copy activity for each sheet? I cannot assume I will know the sheet names or how many sheets there will be. I would prefer to avoid creating multiple datasets for the Excel file if possible.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi@Vanbuskirk Kindly let me know if you need more information. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get list of Excel sheet names in ADF is not support yet and you can vote [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/41283133-get-list-of-excel-sheet-names).

1. So you can use [azure funcion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python) to get the sheet names.

```py
import pandas

xl = pandas.ExcelFile('data.xlsx')

# see all sheet names
print(xl.sheet_names )
```

[image]

2. Then use an Array type variable in ADF to get and traverse this array.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I ended up doing a PowerShell script to extract each worksheet as a csv file then use Azure Automation to run the Powershell Runbook. However, I tested this and it works good as well!