# How to iterare all the excel sheets present in a excel file in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an Excel file with 5 sheets: Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, Sheet 5.
In the future, the user can add Sheet6, Sheet7 as well.

I want to create a pipeline to copy all the sheet data into a single table. I want to iterate all the sheets in excel and copy the data from Sheet to a single table.

As per my approach, I have created an Array variable and assigned ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5"] and I am using a Foreach loop and Inside Foreach, I am copying the Sheet data to a single table.

In my second approach, I am using a Lookup activity to fetch the sheet info from a SQL table and then using foreach loop to copy the sheet's data into the table.

But, in both the approach, whenever a user adds a new sheet, either, I need to update my ADF pipeline (approach 1) or I need to update my SQL table where Sheet info is present.

I don't want to update either the pipeline or SQL table to fetch data from the new additional sheet. It should iterate dynamically and loads all the sheets' data to a single table. It will do always truncate and load.

Answer (score 1):

Currently getting the sheetnames dynamically in ADF is not possible.
So you would have to write a custom logic to get the list of sheet names and then iterate it over foreach.

For that you can leverage Azure automation/Azure function etc and call them in ADF

[ADF - How to copy an Excel Sheet with Multiple Sheets into separate .csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541195/adf-how-to-copy-an-excel-sheet-with-multiple-sheets-into-separate-csv-files)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that this feature is available at this point of time, as Excel is still relatively new for ADF v2, this feature might not be there, but you can submit a feedback or create a feature request for this with Microsoft [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/feedback/)

For continuing the job, you will have to follow the same approach that you are using, adding the names of sheet manually

Alternatively, if you don't want to add the names of the sheet then you can provide the user access to update the ADF parameter by giving a custom role to just update it and then inform them to update the parameter list as soon as they add a new sheet

Thanks!